# Shipping Price depending on Order Total

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, onepage-checkout

I am trying to find a way to display a different shipping price **depending** on the **Order total amount** ?

Comment: Try `Table rate` shipping method. If it doesn't suits to your requirement (not provided here), Go with Custom Shipping Method

Comment: @AnilSuthar The table rate method works great for me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of any other module. magento is awesome as it support lot of features including this one also.

go to `Backend > System > configuration > Sales`  and select shipping method and try with **Table rate** shipping method.

in condition select `Price vs Destination` , than select `Main website` from `current configuration scope` than you can see `export csv` button. download it. than you can enter information as in following image. fill required details and upload back to backend using `import` button

[image]

you can follow this [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/set-up-table-rate-shipping-in-magento/) for more information....

Comment: Great solution. I am new to magento so every little modification seems like huge to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use default Admin > Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules. If this not cover your issue, you need to create new shipping method, where you can calculate shipping price depends on order total.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default shipping method "Table Rate" for this.

In this shipping method you can import CSV file for that zip codes. and set your rates and shipping label there.

OR

You can use web shop matrix shipping method for this.
Both are same in functionality of working.